# ¿Como obtener las coordenadas reales una sola vez al abrir la app y no las coordenadas del cache que entrega getLastKnownLocation?

Tags: android-studio, geolocalización, gps

En mi código, como hago para obtener las coordenadas reales (**ubicación real del punto en el que me encuentro**) al momento en que se abre la app y no las coordenadas desactualizadas que están en el cache que entrega **getLastKnownLocation**

No quiero usar **onLocatioChange()** para actualizar las coordenadas porque consume mucha energía y solo necesito las coordenadas reales una vez, al abrir la app, luego de esto no necesito actualizar las coordenadas.

**Solo necesito las coordenadas reales (ubicación exacta del punto en el que me encuentro) una vez, al abrir la app**

El código que tengo actualmente entrega las coordenadas a través de **getLastKnownLocation**, coordenadas que toma del cache, cache que casi siempre esta desactualizado a menos que se haya actualizado abriendo otra app como google maps.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Activity.java

```
public class activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txtlat; txtlon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

txtlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtlat);
txtlon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtlon);

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity1.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity1.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity1.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123);
}

ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = ubicacion.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (loc != null) {
   latitud_actual = loc.getLatitude();
   longitud_actual = loc.getLongitude();

   textlat.setText(String.valueof(latitud_actual));
   textlon.setText(String.valueof(longitud_actual));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor de geolocalización solo la primera ocasión, puedes usar SharedPreferences, por ejemplo crea los siguientes métodos:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mi_preferencia";

//Guarda valor en preferencias.
public void guardaValor(Context context, Boolean obtuvoGeoLoc) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("geoloc", obtuvoGeoLoc);
    editor.commit();
}

//Obtiene valor desde preferencias
public boolean obtieneValor(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getBoolean("geoloc", false);
}
```

Ahora en tu código puedes usar estos métodos para validar cuando se obtenga la geolocalización, no se obtenga nuevamente:

```
...
...
//Obtiene valor de preferencia (la primera ocasión es por default false).
boolean obtuvoGeoLocalizacion = obtieneValor(getApplicationContext());

//Valida si obtuvo Geolocalización previamente, si no se obtuvo la trata de obtener.
if(!obtuvoGeoLocalizacion){ 
ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = ubicacion.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (loc != null) {
   latitud_actual = loc.getLatitude();
   longitud_actual = loc.getLongitude();

   textlat.setText(String.valueof(latitud_actual));
   textlon.setText(String.valueof(longitud_actual));
    
   //*Si obtuvo la geolocalización, guarda preferencia con valor true y no entrará más a obtener la geolocalización.
   guardaValor(getApplicationContext(), true);

}
}

...
...
```

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys De pronto no me hice entender en mi pregunta. No quiero usar **getLastKnownLocation** para obtener las coordenadas, porque casi siempre entrega coordenadas desactualizadas, tampoco quiero usar **onLocatioChange()**  porque gasta mucha bateria y **solo** necesito las coordenadas exactas y reales del punto en el que me encuentro cuando abro la app.